# Creating Assets after rendering

Tags: php, oop

I have this class I was working on which allows you to create an array of assets like so:

```
array(
    'css' => array(
        array('name' => 'bla'),
        array('name' => 'bla2')
    ),
    'js' => array(
        array('name' => 'bla.js'),
        array('name' => 'bla2.js')
    )    
);
```

This class then parses these and renders out, you would do the following:

```
$assets = new AssetLoader(array(
    'css' => array(
        array('name' => 'bla'),
        array('name' => 'bla2')
    ),
    'js' => array(
        array('name' => 'bla.js'),
        array('name' => 'bla2.js')
    )    
));

$assets->renderAssets();
```

So lets assume you do this in the header.php of your application, you now have two css files and two js files.

If you want to create new assets you would do:

```
$assets->createAssets('css', array('name' => 'bla3'));
```

The problem with createAssets is:

1. It creates the asset, `bla3`, as both a js and a css asset when in fact you are telling it to create a new css asset.
2. You can only do this ABOVE `renderAssets();` which is a problem, you should be able to do it any where in your application, hence the name: `createAssets()`

This is my class:

```
<?php
class AssetLoader {

    private $assets;

    private $cssAssets;

    private $jsAssets;

    public function __construct(array $assets){
        $this->assets = $assets;
        $this->seperateAssets($this->assets);
    }

    public function renderAssets(){
        $this->renderCss();
        $this->renderJs();
    }

    public function createAssets($type, array $assets){
        if(isset($this->assets[$type])){
            array_push($this->assets[$type], $assets);
            $this->seperateAssets($this->assets);

        }
    }

    protected function renderCss(){
       foreach($this->processCss() as $css){
           echo $css;
       }
    }

    protected function renderJs(){
        foreach($this->processJs() as $js){
            echo $js;
        }
    } 

    protected function processCss(){
        $html = array();
        foreach($this->cssAssets as $assetName){
            foreach($assetName as $name=>$location){
                $html[] = '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" name="'.$name.'" href="'.$location.'" />';
            }
        }

        return $html;
    }

    protected function processJs(){
        $html = array();
        foreach($this->cssAssets as $assetName){
            foreach($assetName as $name=>$location){
                $html[] = '<script type="text/javascript" name="'.$name.'" src="'.$location.'"></script>';
            }
        }

        return $html;
    }

    private function seperateAssets(array $assets){
        $this->seperateCss($assets);
        $this->seperateJs($assets);
    } 

    private function seperateCss($assets){
        foreach($assets as $key=>$value){
            if($key == 'css'){
                $this->cssAssets = $value; 
            }
        } 
    }

    private function seperateJs($assets){
        foreach($assets as $key=>$value){
            if($key == 'js'){
                $this->jsAssets = $value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What changes would I have to make in order for **A)** the `createAsset()` to create an asset any where in the application and not before the call to `renderAssets()`, which is called in the header. and B) for the asset you create to be added to the type you define, in the example above you see I am creating a new asset for css, how evr this asset is added to both css and js.

Comment: (A) don't output html-as-you-go, let portions buffer the html, only begin outputting html if _all_ content is known. Output buffering functions can help with the initial rewrite, it would better to let code return strings & let the 'main' page decide when & how to echo it. (B) you call `cssAssets` in `processJs()`...

Comment: @Wrikken Can you expand on A with some examples please?

Comment: (A) is basically instead of `include 'header.inc.php'; incude 'somefilethatechoes.php';`, you run something like `$page_specific_content = include 'somefilethatreturnsastring.php';include 'header.inc.php'; echo $page_specific_content;`. Does that make sense to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `processJs()` method, change this:

```
foreach($this->cssAssets as $assetName){
```

To this:

```
foreach($this->jsAssets as $assetName){
```

Comment: That fixes the "why is css also going into js" issue ... but what about the "how can I call createAssets() any time after i call render and have it just append the new asset ...

Comment: @LogicLooking I would recommend re-factoring the code so that all assets are stored in the object's property until the very moment the assets need rendering in your template.

Comment: so the `processCSS` and `processJS` functions should return the assets back to the `$assets` object and then `renderAssets` should call that and iterate over it? - If I understand this correctly?

Comment: Yes, that approach will allow you to more easily manage your assets